# Updating MVC3 application after altering database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, svn

Thanks in advance for your time :-)

I am working on an MVC3 application and a related database project in visual studio 2010 professional.  I am switching between the projects as I revise database structure.

I'd like to know are there any tricks for updating the controllers and views in my mvc application?  Updating the model (edmx and tt files) is a piece of cake. but it seems to be a huge chore to recreate the model and views without simply deleting them and starting over.

Deleting and starting over wouldn't be too bad if it didn't cause me to loose customization of the views and wreak havoc with my svn system...

Thanks again for any thoughts!

Comment: I may have asked this question too quickly, if you have any further thoughts let us know... http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part7-cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the code generation templates are meant to be run from the start, they are not intended to do change management of your controllers and views. If you have a standard template that you want to use, you can always use the T4 templates to create your own that will generate code that is closer to the end result you want.

But that is your only option, other than coding it by hand.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into T4 templates.  I've never heard of them before...  In my defense, I'm more of a php person...

Comment: After some research, with vs 2010 you need to manually modify your controllers and views after they have been generated.  The good news is that one can create a separate controller/view and do a bit of comparing/contrasting to figure out how to modify the current view.  When you are done modifying your current view, you just toss out the unneeded one.

Answer (score 0):

[MVC Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) would allow you to quickly re-generate views, controllers, repositories etc. However you would lose any customisations.You can customise the T4 templates to make it make pages more like you want.  If your changes were generic that you always did then keeping them in the T4 template would mean they would also be regenerated by the scaffolding.

It is a good way to quickly add new functionality/or replace existing.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks promising.

Comment: No problem. Remember to upvote any answers that help. Let me know if you need any help with it.

Comment: This is a good comment.  I'd upvote it if my rank was high enough.  Thank you.